# Redis geospatial database alters stored latitude and longitude values

Tags: python, redis, coordinates, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I am creating a geospatial database using redis to store all of the bus stop locations in my city. The goal of this is to create a database that is accesible from a python api, where I can query a lat & lon pair and the database returns the nearest bus stop.

All of the location data for the bus stops are stored in a csv file, when I automatically submit the data to redis all at once, the returned lat & lon pairs are slightly altered with a error of 100 - 200 m. This error obviously renders the whole database unusable as I need accurate coords of where the bus stops are.

Code:

```
for _, row in stop_data.iterrows():
    R.geoadd('HSR_stops', (row['stop_lon'], row['stop_lat'], str(row['stop_code'])))

# search the redis database for the bus stop with the lat = 43.291883 and lon = -79.791904 using geosearch
search_results = R.geosearch('HSR_stops', unit='m', radius = 500, latitude = 43.291883, longitude = -79.791904, withcoord=True, withdist=True, withhash=True, sort='ASC')

#print the contents of the search
for result in search_results:
    print(result)
```

Results:

```
[b'2760', 166.9337, 1973289467967760, (-79.79112356901169, 43.290493808825886)]
[b'2690', 248.7088, 1973289468911023, (-79.79344636201859, 43.293816828265776)]
```

However, when I submit a bus stop individually to redis using the same geoadd command the lat  & lon isn't altered and only has an error of <0.5 m.
Code:

```
R.geoadd('HSR_stops', (stop_data['stop_lon'][0], stop_data['stop_lat'][0], str(stop_data['stop_code'][0])))

## same search code as above
```

Results:

```
[b'2760', 0.2105, 1973289468720618, (-79.791901409626, 43.2918828360212)]
```

I have triple checked that nothing is wrong with the data being submitted. And have also tried submitting all of the data in as many different ways as I could think of, as one string and with time delays between each submission etc, nothing fixed the problem.

Why is this happening? What can I do to solve this problem?

TLDR: Redis alters the latitude and longitude stored in a geospatial database when the coordinate data is submitted as a large batch but not individually, what can I do to fix this so I don't have to individually enter each coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check what level of precision Redis is using. It's possible it needs to be told to use a more precise data type for storing floats (or maybe use a decimal type of some sort) and so it may be cropping off the excess though that doesn't quite seem to be the case.

Alternatively, you could try storing the coordinates as strings instead of numbers. Then just parse the strings back to numbers after you fetch it from redis.

Comment: Redis stores the coordinates in a 52-bit integer which can't be changed, regardless it should only have an error of ~0.5 m. 

I have tried sending the coordinates as strings and floats and both resulted in the same error.

Do you have any other suggestions for why this may be happening?